# Laravel ошибка при накатывании миграций

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь выполнить команду:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

В php.ini раскомментировал следующее:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll 
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Вот результат phpinfo():
[image: PHPINFO]

Настройки конфига:

```
'default' => 'mysql', 
'mysql' => [ 
'driver' => 'mysql', 
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), 
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'g***k'), 
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'), 
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), 
'charset' => 'utf8', 
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
'prefix' => '', 
'strict' => false,
```

Вот БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия MySQL: 5.6

Использую сборку LAMPP (XAMPP)

В php.ini нашел следующий комментарий:

```
; For example, on Windows: 
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
```

Насколько я понял, то для UNIX-семейств должен подключаться файл *.so, а у меня в php.ini есть только файл с расширением *.dll. Попробовал вставить строку:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=mysql.so
```

Но ошибка осталась. Может есть возможность их подключить?

Comment: Будьте добры, покажите конфиги подключения к БД. `config/bd.php`, если не ошибаюсь. Конкртеные хосты-логины-пароли можно затереть.

Comment: Настройки подключения точно корректные?

Comment: В пост добавил всю информацию

Comment: Попробуйте password заменить на `null`. Насколько понимаю, пустая строка тоже является паролем.

Comment: Изменил, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Попробуйте вручную PDO проинициализировать. Конкретно ошибка вроде как выскакивает только в случае отсутствия необходимого модуля, хз что тут на самом деле.

Comment: А что выводит `php --ini`?